# How do I turn a web plugin into a function for eventlistner to use

Tags: javascript

I need to turn this script into a function to add to eventlistner to be to use as a function

The code below is the one i need to turn into a function

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@grammarly/editor-sdk?clientId=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></script>
<grammarly-editor-plugin>
<textarea></textarea>
</grammarly-editor-plugin>
```

How can I achieve this?

The code below is an example of how I need the code to look like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.7/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addDarkmodeWidget() {
new Darkmode().showWidget();
}
window.addEventListener('load', addDarkmodeWidget);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call a function that adds Grammarly suggestions to a `textarea` when `load` is fired. Is that right?

If so, you can use the [addPlugin](https://developer.grammarly.com/docs/api/editor-sdk/editorsdk#addplugin) function to add Grammarly suggestions to a text editor.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<script type="module">
  function addGrammarlySuggestions() {
    Grammarly.init().then((grammarly) => {
      grammarly.addPlugin(document.querySelector("textarea"), {
        autocomplete: "on",
        documentDialect: "british"
      });
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", addGrammarlySuggestions);
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@grammarly/editor-sdk@2.0?clientId=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></script>
```

You can try it out on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/74100492-add-event-listener-yv21pp?file=/public/index.html:1592-1674).

If you have specific questions about how to use the Grammarly Text Editor SDK in the future, you can ask them in the [Grammarly for Developers community on GitHub](https://github.com/grammarly/grammarly-for-developers/discussions).